# If "shall / shall not" requirement is violated, then does it matter in which section (e.g. Semantics, Constraints) such requirement is located?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, c11, standards-compliance, c17

If "shall / shall not" requirement is violated, then does it matter in which section (e.g. semantics, constraints) such requirement is located?

Reason of the question: this opinion:

> This is in a Semantics section of the standard, not Constraints, so no diagnostic is required.

Is it true that violation of "shall / shall not" requirement located in the Semantics section does not require a diagnostics?

Comment: See section 5.1.1.3. Interpret as you wish, but imo the quote is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Semantic violations do **not** require a diagnostic message, while constraint violations do.

Section 5.1.1.3p1 of the [C11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding Diagnostics states the following:

> A conforming implementation shall produce at least one diagnostic
> message (identified in an implementation-defined manner) if a
> preprocessing translation unit or translation unit contains a
> violation of any syntax rule or constraint, even if the behavior is
> also explicitly specified  as  undefined  or  implementation-defined.
> Diagnostic  messages  need  not  be produced in other circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

The standard only very loosely defines what "semantics" actually mean. Most importantly, there is no definition of the term in section 3 *Terms, definitions, and symbols* of the standard.

What the standard *does* define in that section is the meaning of "constraint":

> **3.8**
>
> 1 **constraint**
>
> restriction, either syntactic **or semantic**, by which the exposition of
> language elements is to be interpreted

Added emphasis on "...or semantic".

The standard then goes on:

> **4. Conformance**
>
> 1 In this document, "shall" is to be interpreted as a requirement on an implementation or on a program; conversely, "shall not" is to be interpreted as a prohibition.
>
> 2 If a "shall" or "shall not" requirement that appears outside of a constraint or runtime-constraint is violated, the behavior is undefined.

And then we come to:

> **5.1.1.3 Diagnostics**
>
> 1 A conforming implementation shall produce at least one diagnostic message (identified in an implementation-defined manner) if a preprocessing translation unit or translation unit contains a violation of any syntax rule **or constraint**, even if the behavior is also explicitly specified as undefined or implementation-defined.

Added emphasis on "...or constraint".

As per 3.8, being "only" a *semantic restriction* does not rule out something being a *constraint*.

As per 4. 1), a "shall" is a requirement, a "shall not" a prohibition.

I interpret both to indicate a constraint.

As per 5.1.1.3, not only violated syntax rules, but also violated *constraints* require a diagnostic, even if (as per 4. 2)) "[...] the behavior is also explicitly specified as undefined or implementation-defined."

---

Note, however, to avoid misunderstandings:

I am referring here to semantics *specified with a "shall" / "shall not" **in the standard**,* not any which semantics of any which program.